# Delete files & folders recursively

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have so much files and folders. They have a syntax like this path

/opt/logs/qnap/[hosta,hostb]/2012/03/12

### All log file on the Qnap data storage and it is in the another location. So when I want to delete files & folders which are older than 180 days I cannot use find command cause of the slowness. So I wrote a script like this .

```
SixMonthAgo=$(date --date='190 day ago' "+%Y/%m/%d/%H")  = 2011/06/12/12
Hosts="hosta hostb"
maxDay=181
qnapFolder="/opt/logs/qnap"

for host in $(echo "${Hosts}"); do
        maxDayAgo=$(date --date="${maxDay} day ago" "+%Y/%m/%d")
        countCharacters=$(echo ${maxDayAgo} | wc -c)
        if [ ${countCharacters} -ge 10 ]; then
                rm -rf ${qnapFolder}/${host}/${maxDayAgo} #output of this just like 2012/03/12
        fi
done
```

---

But sometimes i got an error. This soluiton is not working correctly what I want. I want to delete all files and folders before 180 days. How can I do this ?  That must delete before all files and directories before 2012/03/23 for example .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The find command is slow? Are you certain? The only drawback is that it fails to remove the directory structure.

`find /opt/logs/qnap -type f -mtime +180 -delete`

If the directories were indeed created at the same time then maybe removing `-type f` could work for you.

`find /opt/logs/qnap -mtime +180 -delete`

find is very fast mind you ... but if you really want to do it with a shell script ...

```
CUTOFF=$(date --date='190 day ago' "+%s)
HOSTS="hosta hostb"
DIRECTORY="/opt/logs/qnap"

for HOST in $(ls -1 $DIRECTORY); do
    if [ -d $DIRECTORY$HOST ]; then
        for DATE in $(ls -1 $DIRECTORY$HOST); do
            if [ -d $DIRECTORY$HOST$DATE ]; then
                if [ "$CUTOFF" < "$(stat --format="%Y" $DIRECTORY$HOST$DATE)" ]; then
                    echo "Deleting $DIRECTORY$HOST$DATE"
                    rm -rf $DIRECTORY$HOST$DATE;
                fi
            fi
        done
    fi
```

Comment: I believe that the original poster has a remote file system (NFS maybe), which is indeed slow. Then, to go faster, he could run that `find` on the file server if possible.

Comment: the find command is not an exact solution for me cause of slowness. Even When I use ls command, I have to wait 40 seconds to list. So how can I loop recursive . Do you have any recommends?

Comment: No, find is probably the fastest you can get. You might write a C program using http://linux.die.net/man/3/ftw which would first collect a list of paths to remove, then remove them.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution just like below. For instance lets say that the day older than 180 days ago is 2012/04/17 . That just deletes all directories starting from 2012/04/17 until 2012/04/01. And secondly it deletes every month before 2012/04 . The deletes ones are 2012/03, 2012/02 and 2012/01.

```
# SixMonthAgo=$(date --date='190 day ago' "+%Y/%m/%d/%H")  = 2011/06/12/12
maxDay=104
qnapFolder="/opt/logs/qnap"
for host in $(echo "${Hosts}"); do
    maxDayAgo=$(date --date="${maxDay} day ago" "+%Y/%m/%d")
    countCharacters=$(echo ${maxDayAgo} | wc -c)
    if [ ${countCharacters} -ge 10 ]; then
        year=$(echo ${maxDayAgo} |cut -d '/' -f 1)
        month=$(echo ${maxDayAgo} |cut -d '/' -f 2) #2012/06
        day=$(echo ${maxDayAgo} |cut -d '/' -f 3) #2012/06/04

        minday=00
        minmonth=00
        until [ $month -le $minmonth ]
        do
            until [ $day -le $minday ]
            do
                rm -rf ${qnapFolder}/${host}/2012/$month/$day
                    day=$(printf "%02d" $(expr $day - 01)) 

            done        

                    month=$(printf "%02d" $(expr $month - 01))
            rm -rf ${qnapFolder}/${host}/2012/$month
        done
    fi
done
```

Thanks

Comment: You have to modify minday and minmonth values to 01 . Otherwise it will try to delete 2012/00 or /2012/04/00